# Can we implement row level security in Tableau version 9.2?

Tags: tableau-api, row-level-security

I am working on a POC where I need to know some features which are available in tableau version 9.2 Due to type of license available, we cannot upgrade to higher version as it will required a different tableau server license.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The feature is provided associating the specific username per attribute: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/row-level-security-and-user-filters

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/publish_userfilters_create.htm